# opening colorbox on a callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [brscPicasa jQuery plugin](http://tech.barszcz.info/projects/brscpicasa-jquery-plugin/) and want to open up [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) when clicking on an album.
I have the demo behaviour working

```
    $.fn.brscPicasa.defaults = {
    photos_thumbsize: '64c',
    photo_displaysize: '320',
    callback: function() {
        $('a.loaded-link img', this).parent().click(function() {
            alert('some lightbox clone could be openening now');
            return false;
        });
    }
};
```

So I get the alert. Now in order to fire the colorbox function I replace the alert like so:

```
            $('a.loaded-link img', this).parent().click(function() {
            $.colorbox();
        });
```

This loads the colorbox, but it doesn't load the picture linked to. What am I missing? I could just

```
$("a").colorbox();
```

But believe this is not the proper way of acting the colorbox after the brscPicasa content is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$('a.loaded-link img', this).parent().click(function() {
    alert('some lightbox clone could be openening now');
    return false;
});
```

You should probably be doing this:

```
$('a.loaded-link').colorbox();
```

That would assign colorbox to the anchor elements with a class of 'loaded-link'.  Then, when a visitor clicked on any of those anchor elements the image would be displayed in colorbox.  If you wanted the images to display as a gallery, you would have to set colorbox's rel property since there doesn't seem to be a native rel attribute set on those anchor elements.  Example:

```
$('a.loaded-link').colorbox({rel:'group1'});
```

Answer (score 0):

if 'a.loaded-link' contains a href to an image, then you can simply use the following as your callback.

```
callback: function() {
    $('a.loaded-link', this).colorbox();
}
```